# How can I pivot longer when I have years as as the first row entry of my dataset (in R)

Tags: r, pivot

How can I pivot my data with R , given that my first row is years. I would like to create a new column with years.

Im unable to use the pivot function, as my data is not stored in another column, but instead in the first row. Additionally, when I import the dataset, the 20 Variables are made into about 260 Variables a (Unique Column ID making one Variable into 15 for 15 different years)

This is how my data looks:

```
tibble(
ID = c(NA, 1,2,3,4),
Region = c(NA, "Region A", "Region B", "Region C", "Region D"), 
Variable1 = c(2017, 1, 2, 3, 4),
Variable1.1 = c(2018, 5, 6, 7, 8),
Variable1.2 = c(2019, 9, 10, 11, 12),
Variable2 = c(2019, 13, 14, 15, 16),
Variable2.1 = c(2020, 17, 18, 19, 20)
)
```

This is how I would like my data to look like:

```
tibble(
ID = c(1,1,1,1,2,2),
Region = c("Region A","Region A","Region A","Region A", "Region B","Region B"), 
Year = c(2017, 2018, 2019, 2020,2017,2018),
Variable1 = c(1,5,9,NA,2,6),
Variable2 = c(NA,NA,13,17,NA,NA)
)
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please [do not post code or data in images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2372064)

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks, I just made two tibbles that show exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 3):

If you start with a data.frame named `dd`

```
dd <- tibble(
  ID = c(NA, 1,2,3,4),
  Region = c(NA, "Region A", "Region B", "Region C", "Region D"), 
  Variable1 = c(2017, 1, 2, 3, 4),
  Variable1.1 = c(2018, 5, 6, 7, 8),
  Variable1.2 = c(2019, 9, 10, 11, 12),
  Variable2 = c(2019, 13, 14, 15, 16),
  Variable2.1 = c(2020, 17, 18, 19, 20)
)
```

You would need to transform it into a more "normal" data.frame with the data in the headers, not in the rows.

```
names(dd)[-(1:2)]<-paste(gsub("\\..*$","",names(dd)[-(1:2)]), as.character(dd[1,-(1:2)]), sep="_")
dd <- dd[-1,]
head(dd)
#      ID Region   Variable1_2017 Variable1_2018 Variable1_2019 Variable2_2019 Variable2_2020
#   <dbl> <chr>             <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>
# 1     1 Region A              1              5              9             13             17
# 2     2 Region B              2              6             10             14             18
# 3     3 Region C              3              7             11             15             19
# 4     4 Region D              4              8             12             16             20
```

Then you can do a standard pivot

```
tidyr::pivot_longer(dd, -c(ID, Region), names_sep="_", names_to=c(".value", "year"))
#       ID Region   year  Variable1 Variable2
#    <dbl> <chr>    <chr>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#  1     1 Region A 2017          1        NA
#  2     1 Region A 2018          5        NA
#  3     1 Region A 2019          9        13
#  4     1 Region A 2020         NA        17
# ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast reply. For some reason when I pivot, this gives me duplicate (or more) Year and Region combinations? And many values get lost in the process

Comment: Are you trying it with the data provided? I can't seem to replicate that particular error.

Comment: the problem was with the regex code, for some reason it didnt split the columns correctly and I had multiple year + unit observations (e.g. Region A 2017 more than once), I used "\\.[0-9]{1,2}$" to fix this. 

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

There's a function in the `unheadr` package for this.

```
dd |>
  unheadr::mash_colnames(1)
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 4 × 7
     ID Region   Variable1_2017 Variable1.1_2018 Variable1.2_2019 Variable2_2019 Variable2.1_2020
  <dbl> <chr>             <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>          <dbl>            <dbl>
1     1 Region A              1                5                9             13               17
2     2 Region B              2                6               10             14               18
3     3 Region C              3                7               11             15               19
4     4 Region D              4                8               12             16               20
```

Or your could just use the 1st row:

```
dd |>
  unheadr::mash_colnames(1,keep_names = FALSE)
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 4 × 7
   `NA` `NA`     `2017` `2018` `2019` `2019` `2020`
  <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1 Region A      1      5      9     13     17
2     2 Region B      2      6     10     14     18
3     3 Region C      3      7     11     15     19
4     4 Region D      4      8     12     16     20
Warning message:
In unheadr::mash_colnames(dd, 1, keep_names = FALSE) :
  possible NA values in variable names, check the `n_name_rows` argument
```

Comment: Thanks Jon, that packages is very helpful in general